# JWT .Net and Java compatibility issue

Tags: java, c#, jwt

I want to generate a JWT token from WPF app. I am supposed to send this JWT token in the web API calls as Authorization token.
I am creating JWT from .net using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` and `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` libraries. Entire method implementation is listed below.

```
public static string GenerateToken()
{
    string secretKey = "2A590574A992810FD98FF1E02F1FC7FBFFA0DF8304957CD86E29805B53E0EA9D";
    string signatureAlgo = "HS256";

    TimeSpan ts = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));
    string millis = ((long)ts.TotalMilliseconds).ToString();

    TimeSpan expt = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).Add(new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));
    long dt = ((long)expt.TotalSeconds);

    var claims = new Claim[]{
        new Claim("clientId","some-client-ID"),
        new Claim("exp", dt.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.Integer64),
        new Claim("ts", millis.ToString())
    };

    SecurityKey securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey));

    SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, signatureAlgo);
    JwtHeader header = new JwtHeader(signingCredentials);
    JwtPayload payload = new JwtPayload(claims);

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

When I pass JWT generated from above method to API, it is not able to validate the JWT. API code is written in Java.

Contrary to the above mentioned approach of JWT generation, if I generate JWT online from https://www.javainuse.com/jwtgenerator and pass the online generated JWT to the API then API is able to validate the token.

So currently I am not able to figure out what could be the possible correction in JWT generation in .net which will enable the APIs algo to validate the JWT.

**Note:** Regarding secret key conversion to byte array.

Since the above key is in HEX format I have also tried below mentioned method to convert the hex string to byte array which gives an array of 32 bytes where as the `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` method is giving an array of 64 bytes. But in any case token is not getting authenticated.

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

Edit1 : Have changed claim value type from "long" to `ClaimValueTypes.Integer64`

Comment: With `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` you're just getting the byte values of each character while hex encoding means that for example "2A" is interpreted as two 4 bit values. So you need to decide how to use the secret and it must be the same on both ends. Could you please show the C#  and online generated tokens? Then it might be easier to see what is the actual difference.

Comment: Token generated from code: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjbGllbnRJZCI6InNvbWUtY2xpZW50LUlEIiwiZXhwIjoiMTY3NTQxMzAzNCIsInRzIjoiMTY3NTQxMTIzMzY4MyJ9.KSwTlrn2EiTA04XKDCvJBlft3B2zu_01Vemc7zdRyfU

Comment: Token generated from online: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjbGllbnRJZCI6InNvbWUtY2xpZW50LUlEIiwiZXhwIjoxNjc1NDQ3MzExLCJ0cyI6IjE2NzU0MTEzNjk1NjAifQ.aJ6t1oV5dqJogLZwMp4bL3jt2gQuBK9ojwKQzAmaKZ8

Comment: I am using https://jwt.io/ to decode the token online for verification purpose if claims are proper or not

Comment: Did you use the same secret as in the code above? In the linked jwtgenerator you can just paste a string for the secret, right? But I can't verify any of the tokens on jwt.io with the secret from the code.

Comment: Yes, I have used the same secret key as mentioned in the code snippet in the original question

Comment: Could you also show the Java code that is used to verify?

Comment: That I do not have. It is with API creator. We just know that it is written in Java. API Creators won't share their code with us. Still let me try to get a code snippet from them.